# Incorrect entry of another person's calendar in Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010, calendar

We migrated from exchange 2003 to 2010. All mailboxes are locate in 2010 now.
Next, we are replacing client computers from windows XP with Outlook 2003 to Windows7 with Outlook 2010.

Some user reported "another person's calendar entry that deleted long before have restored".

I know 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2685949 (japanese only), but this KB talk about entry disappear. not about reappear.

Anyone have information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen in only in Outlook? How about an iPhone or Blackberry?

I would delete the OST file and let it rebuild, could be something got stuck in there.

Comment: Yes. It happen in only in Outlook 2010.
In the first place, iPhone doesn't have function to view another person's calendar(I don't know about Blackberry) .

I tried Deleting OST file, but it doesn't resolve this issue.